# Locally accessible dimensions of configuration space

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spacetime-dimensions, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

I am reading a book called "Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics"
by MIT Press.While discussing configuration space and degrees of freedom,the authors remark the following:

> Strictly speaking, the dimension of the configuration space and the number of degrees of freedom are not the same. The number of degrees of freedom is the dimension of the space of configurations that are ``locally accessible.'' For systems with integrable constraints the two are the same. For systems with non-integrable constraints the configuration dimension can be larger than the number of degrees of freedom.

I am aware of the distinction between holonomic and non-holonomic consraints.But I can't relate what the authors mean by **locally accessible dimensions**.

Can someone shed light on this matter ?A dynamical system which explains the idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Imagine the blade of an ice-skate, the center of mass can be taken to the whole frozen lake, but the blade can't move sideways, so locally the "side"-dimension is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a coin (modeled as an infinitesimally thin disk of radius $R$) which rolls without slipping on a tabletop.  For simplicity, assume that the plane of the coin remains vertical at all times. The space of allowable configurations is given by four variables:

- The position $(x,y)$ of the contact point with the table;
- The orientation of the plane of the coin relative to the $x$-axis, given by an angle $\alpha$.
- The angle of some fixed point on the coin's rim relative to the vertical, given by some angle $\theta$.

However, we cannot freely change each of these four variables independently of each other.  Their infinitesimal changes are related by
$$
dx = R \cos \alpha \, d\theta, \qquad dy = R \sin \alpha \, d\theta.
$$
In other words, we can only make two infinitesimal changes independently of each other, and that determines the infinitesimal changes in the other two.  So the system only has two degrees of freedom.

Because we're talking about infinitesimal changes, this is why the authors refer to these changes as "locally accessible."  But by making bigger ("global") changes in the system, we can bring the system into "locally inaccessible" configurations.  For example, you can't rotate $\theta$ by some angle $\delta \theta$ while keeping $x$ and $y$ constant (without violating the rolling-without-slipping constraint.)  But you can roll the coin around in a circle of just the right circumference so that when it returns to the original spot on the table, $\theta$ has changed by any angle you choose.  In general, it's possible to get the coin into any configuration of $\{x,y,\alpha, \theta\}$ that you want, so the configuration space really is four-dimensional;  but because you can't freely choose all four of the infinitesimal variations, the system only has two degrees of freedom.

Answer (score -1):

'Locally accessible dimensions' is not a standard term but an example would presumably be the following:

Imagine a ball rolling inside a hemispherical bowl. It is locally constrained to a two-dimensional surface. But given enough force the ball may escape and access the entirety of three-dimensional space.